# Error while editing array which have data assigned in pageload in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, arrays, pageload

I have a problem in jQuery while editing in array.
First on page load i have to assign values in array by AJAX call.

For example

```
var purchase = [];
---ajax call
ajax sucess:function(data){
$.each(data.d,function(index,value){
   var purchaseDetail = new object();
   purchaseDetail .Name=value.Name;
   purchaseDetail .partNo=value.partNo;
   purchase.push(purchaseDetail);

  Bind in div with button with class btn_edit
  bindintable();<---- Here the data in array purchase is bind with button class edit and index as id(for eg <td><input type='button' class='edit' id='edit_0' >)

$('.edit').on('click',function(){
   get id by split 
   purchase[id].Name = something something
   purchase[id].partNo = something something
});

 });
}
```

Let's assume

```
 Purchase = {Name:"John", partNo:2},{Name:"max", partNo:3},{Name:"Roy", partNo:4}......
```

While adding a new item or editing in the array purchase, I get this

```
Purchase = {Name:"John", partNo:2},{Name:"John", partNo:2},{Name:"John", partNo:2}......
```

Can anyone suggest why this is happening?
But it is happening if data is not assigned in pageload

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance

Comment: Can we see your 'get id by split' code? It might be easier to use a data attribute such as data-id on your buttons and then get it like this $(this).data( "id" )

Comment: Does you code have these spaces in `purchaseDetail .Name=value.Name;`   and also in `purchaseDetail .partNo=value.partNo;` or are those typos here?

Comment: Please post your php file where you are performing the query. Is important, in order to spot the problem to check how you pass the response to the ajax call.

Comment: @Tokn yes it is like as you have written 
var getId=  $(this).attr('id');
var spliteddata =  getId.split('_');
then we get the id of that particular index by parseInt(spliteddata[1]);
as the id assigned is like ('edit_1') 
all of this is dynamically bind

Comment: @DelightedD0D no there is no spaces in purchaseDetail .Name=value.Name; or any of those typos

Comment: @Franco i am using jQuery in asp.net and Here only one time at Pageload the Ajax call is made and the data is assigned to an array purchase. 
At Ajax succes i pass a list that contains the datas that is saved to a function which further dynamically binds the whole structure like 
`<tr><td>Name : "+ value.Name +" </td><tr>`.At that time i am getting the desiered data and it is binding just as i want without repeating but when i try to edit the array's data then the data in the last index replaces is seen on every index